# Should there be a separate profile identifier for users who mostly answer questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen many users who have asked 0 or very few questions in Stack Overflow, but they have answered thousands of questions. So if you calculate their question to answer ratio, it would be less than 1%.

However there are users with 10k 20k or more points due to some good quality questions, but they don't answer that many questions.
So my suggestion is that shouldn't the users who mostly answers question, rather than asking them, be rewarded/segregated from others. (Like a different tag say Platinum, or a different color in Profile, etc.)

PS: This doesn't mean I am undermining the users who ask good quality questions as they are the reason we are here, learning and creating a solid database of good question.

Comment: All that only for a more accurate "question to answer ratio"? Does that ratio matter that much?

Comment: No. It is not about ratio. It is about seggregating users who gained reputation by answering more questions than asking questions, with those who mostly ask questions but don't answer that much

Comment: And what would be the point of this? What are you trying to achieve with that segregation? This feature request is pretty unclear to me.

Comment: I was thinking of a different kind of badge like platinum or something in the profile. But I agree with Alon point as well that there are very few cases like that and there are already badges for that.

Comment: Mebbe those who have asked many more questions than they have answered could get a vampire skull with long fangs, or perhaps those who consistently answer noob questions instead of linking a dup get a red light?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see how fancy profile page will help, if "help" is the right word here. What if a user just answer questions, but their answers are terrible? Should they also get that reward too?

Please note that users that only ask questions and never/rarely answer will unlikely to get any of the [Answer Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), so there is already a unique prizes for answering on SO.

It's also pretty rare to see high reputations users who earned it by asking. I know they exist, I see them sometimes, but they are cool and I don't think they should be treated differently.

Comment: I agree that they shouldn't be treated differently. But do you think there should be a different Badge like Platinum or something for those users who spend more time answering.

Comment: You usually see it by the reputation. As I wrote in my answer - I rarely see these types of "anomalies" where a user have 10k+ rep just by asking (Although I know it exist). If you answer, you get more badges and more reputations, and you also helping more, which is a prize for itself :)

Comment: I agree with your point of that there are very few `anomalies`. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

To give you another extreme perspective, [this particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman?tab=profile) has resonated in my mind <s>for reasons</s>, and has made the *vast majority* of their reputation by asking questions.

What's the difference between a user that participates by only asking questions, and a user that participates by only answering questions?  Honestly, none.  They both have the same opportunities to earn the same badges, and frankly, the badges they can earn are reward enough.

No reason to distinguish them any differently than any of the rest of us.  They're participating *too*.

Comment: `73K` rep, `2,212` questions, 16 answers - That user deserves a spot in the StackOverflow Hall of Fame

Comment: @AlonEitan - That user has had some fame on meta.se https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Blankman